# Increasing speed of Azure to make web service

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am using Azure ML. I trained my data approximately in 20 min but when I try to make web service It didn't compiled even in 24 hours. How can I make this process faster? Which kind of resources(memory or... ) should I Buy to increase speed ? please share the link of that resource to buy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aziz, I'd recommend checking the following documentation, it provides information about the specific VMs to be used for ML: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/data-science-virtual-machines/ , Choose the OS you'd like, then click on Plan+ Pricing, and it will give you the instance's cost based on storage type, CPU, RAM etc..

Comment: can you tell  how to increase speed of  making web service(because training didn't take too much time) ?

Comment: Yes, you should consider adding additional endpoints if you have a high load, check you the following documentation related to Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/scaling-webservice

Comment: you're welcome Aziz, feel free to ask any other questions if you need any info.